# Getting entities' dirty fields after saving with associations

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm trying to log each action (insert/update/delete) in the application and I'm doing this by getting the `dirty` and `original` values after saving the entity. The problem is that all values of the associated entities are returned as dirty and even `is_new` flag is set to `true` but actually I'm updating. What causes this behavior and how can I avoid it?

Example:

```
$data = [
    'name'      => $name,
    'something' => $something,
    'Table1'    => [
        'id'     => $idWhereUpdatingTable1,
        'field1' => $field1,
        'field2' => $field2,
    ],
    'Table2'    => [
        'id'     => $idWhereUpdatingTable2,
        'field3' => $field3,
        'field4' => $field4,
    ],
];
$options = ['associated' => ['Table1', 'Table2']];

$updatedEntity = $this->patchEntity($entity, $data, $options);
$save = $this->save($updatedEntity);

// Successfully logging the changes in the main entity

// Trying to log the changes in the associated entities
foreach($save->table1 as $entity)
{
    // everything here is set to dirty (even ID field but it's not an insert) and I'm not able to fetch the updated fields only. Also getOriginal() doesn't return the old values.
}
```

Comment: If you are updating an entry are you using a get or find to retrieve the record you intend to update.

Comment: Yes, I'm loading the main entity with `$this->get($id)`. The associated entities in the other tables are not loaded, I'm passing their IDs in data array as you see in the example, so they will be updated and not inserted/duplicated. All the savings works fine, just can't get the dirty fields for the associated entities.

Answer (score 3):

I did some digging into the `dirty()` function within an Entity and according to the API if you do not explicitly ask it to check a property then it will just tell you if the Entity has any dirty properties.

So doing

`$entity->dirty('title');` Tells you if the tile is dirty but running `$entity->dirty();` will just tell you if any property in the entity is dirty.

http://api.cakephp.org/3.1/class-Cake.ORM.Entity.html#_dirty

Comment: The problem is that all fields are marked as dirty but actually only some of them are updated.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to make code conditional based on whether or not fields have changed in an entity.

For example, you may only want to validate fields when they change:

```
// See if the title has been modified. CakePHP version 3.5 and above
$entity->isDirty('title');

// CakePHP 3.4 and Below use dirty()
$entity->dirty('title');
```